# How to solve JSS application error "Error: Valid value for rootItemId not provided and failed to auto-resolve app root item."

Tags: jss, xm-cloud

When I deploy a JSS Next.js application to Sitecore (XM Cloud on local container, Sitecore demo portal) I get the following error when I run my Next.js application on http://localhost:3000:

[image: rootItemId error]

In text:

```
Server Error
Error: Valid value for rootItemId not provided and failed to auto-resolve app root item.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Using JSS version 20.1.3

How can this error be prevented?

Comment: Can you include texts from your screenshots as code blocks? That helps with SEO and therefore helps others to find your question and answer.

Comment: What version of JSS are you using.

Comment: @RichardSeal I'm using JSS version 20.1.3

Comment: FWIW this is solution very close to this from July 2022, maybe doesn't quite have the simplest the path the folder.
https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/how-to-fix-sitecore-nextjs-jss-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the dictionary service and the sitemap service need a root item ID. This root item ID must be configured in two files:

- `<jss-app>\src\lib\dictionary-service-factory.ts`
- `<jss-app>\src\lib\sitemap-fetcher\plugins\graphql-sitemap-service.ts`

In both files, the comments described how to solve the issue.

For `<jss-app>\src\lib\dictionary-service-factory.ts`:

[image: dictionary-service-factory.ts]

For `<jss-app>\src\lib\sitemap-fetcher\plugins\graphql-sitemap-service.ts`:

[image: graphql-sitemap-service.ts]

And the GUID to be used is the template ID of the `home` item of your JSS app:

[image: rootItemId location]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are getting this error with a Headless SXA site and wish to use the `nextjs-multisite` add-on, do not set the `rootItemId` for the `GraphQLDictionaryService` as the service will only resolve one of your sites. Instead do one of the following:

### Only using Headless SXA sites

If your app is only going to be used with Headless SXA sites, update the `GraphQLDictionaryService` configuration in `src\lib\dictionary-service-factory.ts` with `jssAppTemplateId: '9ed6640464c9412290e1869cb3cea566',` as follows:

```typescript
return new GraphQLDictionaryService({
  endpoint: config.graphQLEndpoint,
  apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
  siteName,
  jssAppTemplateId: '9ed6640464c9412290e1869cb3cea566', // SXA "Headless Site" template ID
  /*
    The Dictionary Service needs a root item ID in order to fetch dictionary phrases for the current
    app. If your Sitecore instance only has 1 JSS App, you can specify the root item ID here;
    otherwise, the service will attempt to figure out the root item for the current JSS App using GraphQL and app name.
    rootItemId: '{GUID}'
  */
})
```

### Using both Headless SXA sites and "vanilla" Headless Services sites

If your app is going to be used for both Headless SXA sites and "vanilla" Headless Services sites, add the Headless Services `App` template (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/JavaScript Services/App`) as a base template to the Headless SXA `Headless Site` template (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Headless Site`).

This is the approach that the XM Cloud team has taken if you'd like to implement the "official" fix. This will of course require you to serialize and track the `Headless Site` template in your code repository.

### Analysis

For analysis of this, see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/1556.

Answer (score 0):

If your Sitecore instance has more than one JSS app, which is likely if you are working on `XM Cloud`, you will not be able to set the `rootItemId` as noted by Sitecore's comment

```
/*
The Dictionary Service needs a root item ID in order to fetch dictionary phrases for the current
app. If your Sitecore instance only has 1 JSS App, you can specify the root item ID here;
otherwise, the service will attempt to figure out the root item for the current JSS App using GraphQL and app name. 
rootItemId: '{GUID}'
*/
```

To resolve ensure value is the same for the following things

1. The Item name of your `Headless Site` item
2. The value of both `name` and `appName` in your site's Next app `package.json`
3. The `Application Name` in the `Rendering Host` (e.g. `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/Rendering Hosts/<YourSite>`.
4. I also recommend confirming that your Rendering Host item is correctly referenced in the `Predefined application rendering host` field of your Site's `Site Grouping` Item (e.g. `~/<Your Site>/Settings/Site Grouping/<Your Site>`)

Doing so will allow the `rootItemId` to be determined via `GraphQL`

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I decided to delete `/sitecore/content/tenant-name/site-name/Home` and removed all links. When I set up `Start Item` again in `/sitecore/content/tenant-name/site-name/Settings/Site Grouping/site-name`, the error gone.